# mysql privileges on table user can't grant

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have granted a user with "database-specific" privilege types. This user was created with the following php mysql query:

```
$queryGrant = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseX.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd' WITH GRANT OPTION ;";
```

In my phpmyadmin, in the table of the privileges windows of `databaseX`, the column `grant` for the user says `yes`. I'm now trying to run the following query as the user just created

```
$queryCGrant = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseX.TableY TO 'TableYusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Ypwd' WITH GRANT OPTION ;";
```

It returns:

```
Could not grant priv
You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

Why the created user with all privileges on `databaseX` can not grant a user with privilege on a table of the same database?

Comment: why are your trying to create an user and give him privileges on the same statement? Can't you use 2 statements -- like normal dba administrators do -- 1 for create the user, and another to give him privileges?

Comment: I'm learning... else I realized that mysql allows to create a user using the Grant query. So far, at the end, a user is created but it seems he has permissions on a database that can't be used.

Comment: why don't you use two statements? like every1 does?

Comment: "Normally, a database administrator first uses CREATE USER to create an account, then GRANT to define its privileges and characteristics. For example: " from the mySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Would it be different if I use two statements for the same purpose?

Comment: yes, it's less likely that you mess up...